# Changes of ispell.el from GNU emacs v27.2 from v26.3?

Tags: microsoft-windows, ispell

Recently, I updated my GNU emacs from v26.3 to v27.2. Now, ispell does not work anymore under Windows 10 (on my Macs, it still works). On my Windows machine, I use hunspell, which has been the same v1.7.0. I am wondering what should be changed in my setup ~/.emacs.d/init.el for the ispell in v27.2 to work. Just as an experiment, if I replace /usr/share/emacs/27.2/lisp/textmodes/ispell.[el,elc] by those of 26.3, the ispell system works under v27.2. That means that some setting in the new ispell.el has changed. My current setup in ~/.emacs.d/init.el is the following, which I copied from the posting [Tutorial: spellchecking with hunspell (1.7.0) for emacs (26.2) on Windows (10) : emacs (reddit.com)](https://www.reddit.com/r/emacs/comments/dgj0ae/tutorial_spellchecking_with_hunspell_170_for/)

```
(autoload 'ispell-message "ispell"
  "Check spelling of mail message or news post.")
(setq ispell-program-name "hunspell")
(setq ispell-library-directory "C:/ProgramData/dict-en")
(setq ispell-hunspell-dict-paths-alist '(("en_US" "C:/ProgramData/dict-en/en_US.aff")))
(setq ispell-local-dictionary "en_US")
(setq ispell-local-dictionary-alist
;; Please note the list `("-d" "en_US")` contains ACTUAL parameters passed to hunspell
;; You could use `("-d" "en_US,en_US-med")` to check with multiple dictionaries
'(("en_US" "[[:alpha:]]" "[^[:alpha:]]" "[']" nil ("-d" "en_US") nil utf-8)))
;; the following line won't make flyspell-mode enabled by default as you might think
(setq ispell-personal-dictionary "C:/Users/me/.hunspell_en_US")
(flyspell-mode 1)
;; ispell-word for showing correcting options of the current misspelled word
;(global-set-key (kbd "M-\\") 'ispell-word
```

If I use the ispell.el of v27.2, I got the error message: `ispell: Can’t find Hunspell dictionary with a .aff affix file`

Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: In case it's a bug in 27.2 which is fixed in 28.1, you could consider updating to that.

Answer (score 0):

I just found a solution. If I insert the following line after setting up ispell-local-dictionary-alist in my init.el:

```
(setq ispell-hunspell-dictionary-alist ispell-local-dictionary-alist)
```

Thanks!